# Editing CSS in Chrome Developer Tools on MacOS?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I used to be able to just click on CSS the value in the Chrome Developer Tools and edit it.

Now the values are locked in both the computed and styles tabs.  If I click on a value in computed, it switches the view to the styles tab and if I click / double click on the value there it's still locked.

How do we edit the values in the Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: Are you using some specific version? I know on mac it can be finnicky and you have to tap at it a few times to get it to editable mode. I just tried on latest on mac and couldn't reproduce your issue on chrome but I switched to Edge personally for most stuff.

Comment: @ChrisW I'm using version 99.0.4844.51.  And I ended up just closing all the windows and restarting and now it works.  I'm guessing there's a bug that can cause it to lock, because I tried for a long time and many different fields in both the styles and computed tabs and it would not let me edit.